# Find the first shock time of Burgers' Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> Find the maximal $t_0>0$ such that the Cauchy problem:
>   $$uu_x+u_t=0 \qquad{} u(x,0)=e^{-x^2/2}$$
>   exists in $\Bbb{R}\times[0,t)$; i.e. find the first time $t=t_0$ when the shock develops.

This is review for my PDE class, using Evans' textbook.

A shock develops when two characteristics intersect, so lets compute the characteristics:

$$\dot{x}=z$$
$$\dot{t}=1$$
$$\dot{z}=0$$

Note $x(0)=x_0$, $t(0)=0$ and $z(0)=e^{-x_0^2/2}$. We may solve the ODEs now:

$$z(s)=e^{-x_0^2/2}$$
$$t(s)=s$$
$$x(s)=se^{-x_0^2/2}+x_0$$

So our characteristic curves are $(se^{-x_0^2/2}+x_0,s)$

Now we need to find when they cross. So pick $x_1,x_2$ for $x_0$ and find intersection:
$$se^{-x_1^2/2}+x_1=se^{-x_2^2/2}+x_2$$

We can solve this and get:

$$s=\frac{x_1-x_2}{e^{-x_2^2/2}-e^{-x_1^2/2}}$$

Now we want to minimize this, I assume. I took the derivatives and set them equal to $0$ but it gets really ugly.

Does anyone have any hints? I'd prefer hints to full answers.

Comment: You are essentially asking for which $s$ is the function $f_s(x) = se^{-x^2/2}+x$ injective. So you could look at if $f'_s(x)$ is ever zero.

Comment: @JoeyZou Thank you! Please check my answer, is it okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per hint, we want to find for which $s$ is the function $f_x(x)=se^{-x^2/2}+x$ injective. It is injective when $f_s'(x)>0$. So compute:

$$f_s'(x)=-sxe^{-x^2/2}+1>0$$

So:

$$1>sxe^{-x^2/2}$$

Since $s>0$ we can consider $x>0$ so we divide:

$$\frac{e^{x^2/2}}{x}>s$$

We find the minimum of $\frac{e^{x^2/2}}{x}$ which is $e^{1/2}$ at $x=1$. So we know that for $s<\sqrt{e}$ the function is injective. Thus our $t_0=\sqrt{e}$.

Comment: Looks good to me! (In the last few lines, you write $e^{x^2}$ when I think you mean $e^{x^2/2}$.) I realized that my hint was slightly incomplete, in that if $f_s$ is not injective and $f_s(x_1) = f_s(x_2)$ with $x_1\ne x_2$, then we need to check that $u(x_1,0)\ne u(x_2,0)$ as well, since otherwise the characteristics are still consistent. But if $se^{-x_1^2/2}+x_1 = se^{-x_2^2/2}+x_2$ and $x_1\ne x_2$, then $se^{-x_1^2/2}\ne se^{-x_2^2/2}$ and so $e^{-x_1^2/2}\ne e^{-x_2^2/2}$.

Comment: @JoeyZou Thanks for your help.